# "size" vs "readelf -t" command gives different segment length

Tags: linux-kernel, size, objdump, readelf

`size my_obj.o`, lists the size of `text, .data segments` in bytes.

but `readelf -t my_obj.o` gives different size (much lesser) of text & data segments.

```
 **text    .data   .bss**
 200890   4797     88   
 146172   1960     88
```

object dump also gives similar results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size` by default runs in "Berkeley compatibility mode".
In this mode, it will include certain non-executable read-only sections that have the ALLOC bit set, such as `.rodata`, as text, and it will classify some non-executable non-NOBITS sections as data instead of bss.
If you run `size` in "System V compatibility mode", `size -A my_obj.o`, it should give you sizes close to the values reported by `readelf -t`.